# Error with member function template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++-6

I am getting compilation error in below code.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
    }
    ~A()
    {
    }
 void func()
 {
     cout <<"Ha ha ha \n";
 }

};

class C
{
public:
    C()
    {
    }
    ~C()
    {
    }
template<typename type> func()
{
    type t;
    t.func();
}
void callme()
{
    func<A>();
}
};
```

Comment: error C2275: 'A' : illegal use of this type as an expression

Comment: How are you calling `callme()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC6 doesn't support member function templates. You actually have several solutions:

Move `func()` out of the class definition

```
template<typename type> void func()
{
    type t;
    t.func();
}
```

or rewrite `callme()`

```
void callme()
{
   A a;
   a.func();
}
```

or use class template

```
class C
{
public:
   template<class T> struct func
   {
      void operator()()
      {
         T t;
         t.func();
      }
   };

   void callme()
   {
      func<A>()();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `func<T>()` doesn't specify its return type, which is invalid in C++.

It should be:

```
template<typename type> void func()
{
    type t;
    t.func();
}
```

Comment: But that is not the actual problem .

Comment: @sat, g++ compiles the code without errors if I add the return type. Does the Visual Studio compiler still give the same error?

Comment: I am working on old VC6 compiler ...this means VC6 is culprit ..Thanks a lot for your immediate reply